# getSupportMenuInflater() and getSherlockActivity() not recognised in actionbarsherlock android

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

I have been trying to inflate a menu using actionbarsherlock, but no luck. please suggest what is wrong.
here is my code:

```
 @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(com.actionbarsherlock.view.Menu menu) {

            MenuInflater inflater=getSherlockActivity().getSupportMenuInflater(); //getSherlockActivity() not recognised
inflater.inflate(R.menu.widgets_menu, menu);

  // I have also tried this:
//MenuInflater inflater=getSupportMenuInflater();// getSupportMenuInflater() not recognized
//inflater.inflate(R.menu.widgets_menu, menu);

 return true;

        }
```

Note: I have imported all the necessary classes

```
import com.actionbarsherlock.ActionBarSherlock;
import com.actionbarsherlock.ActionBarSherlock.OnCreateOptionsMenuListener;
import com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockActivity;
import com.actionbarsherlock.view.Menu;
import com.actionbarsherlock.view.MenuInflater;
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: does your activity class extend `SherlockActivity` (instead of android.app.Activity) ?

Comment: @petrch: Is it necessary? My activity class extends Activity...

Comment: @petrch: hey, that worked. Now the gerSupportMenuInflater() is working fine. But there is another problem in this method:- 
 public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(android.view.Menu menu)  {
  // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
  return mSherlock.dispatchCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
 }// This method is saying that we cannot override final method from SherlockActivity

Comment: you must override `onCreateOptionsMenu(com.actionbarsherlock.view.Menu)` - note the parameter type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally got the answer. Thanks to @petrch.

I just extended my activity class to SherlockActivity.

```
@Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(com.actionbarsherlock.view.Menu menu) {

            MenuInflater inflater=getSherlockActivity().getSupportMenuInflater(); 
inflater.inflate(R.menu.widgets_menu, menu);

 return true;

        }
```